# Local port forwarding - macOs Big Sur

Tags: windows, macos, port-forwarding, netsh

I need to forward all traffic going to 127.0.0.1:5432 to 192.168.1.103:543 on macOS Big Sur. Similar command on Windows is

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=127.0.0.1 listenport=5432 connectaddress=192.168.1.103 connectport=5433
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the rdr command in order to forward traffic from  127.0.0.1:5432 to 192.168.1.103:543

```
echo "

rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to self port 5432 -> 192.168.1.103 port 543

rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to any port 5432 -> 192.168.1.103 port 543

rdr pass on en1 inet proto tcp from any to any port 5432 -> 192.168.1.103 port 543

" | sudo pfctl -ef -
```